# Set repositories and version/revison dynamically in gradle

Tags: gradle, ivy

I have a gradle buildscript. In this script I set some publications.

Later in the script I have a task which reads the Buildnumber from a file and increases it. Than the version of the project will be changed.

Now my question: Is it possible to change the revision/version after initialising the "Publishing"-PlugIn? If I doesn't set the new version, the "Publishing"-PlugIn will throw n error. If I change the version by editing the descriptor, the Plugin says, that it's not allowed to edit the descriptor directly.

I also want to change the repository-url, based on the build number.

Does anybody know a fix or had the same problem?

```
publishing {
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            organisation project.group
            module project.name
            revision project.version
            descriptor.status = 'milestone'

            from components.java

            artifact(sourceJar) {
                type "source"
                conf "runtime"
            }
        }
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version

            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        ivy {
            // change to point to your repo, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            url "P:/Java/Repo/ivy"
        }
        maven {
            // change to point to your repo, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            url "P:/Java/Repo/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my script for increasing the build number

```
def incVersion(project) {

    project.versionInced = true

    def versionPropsFile = file("${project.rootDir}/version.properties")

    if (!versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
         versionPropsFile.createNewFile();
    }

    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    if(versionProps['build_version'] == null)
    {
        versionProps['build_version'] = 0;
    }

    def code = versionProps['build_version'].toInteger()+1;

    versionProps['build_version']=code.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    project.projectInfos.version = project.version + "." + code.toString()
    project.version = project.projectInfos.version

    println "Version: "+project.version 

    return project.version
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, yes it can be done *dynamically*. You can pass a version while running gradle via project property (`-P`) or via system property (`-D`).

It will be:

```
gradle <some_task> -PsomeVersion=<version>
```

You need to alter the gradle script to read the property, so:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            revision project.hasProperty('someVersion') ? project.someVersion : '<HERE YOU NEED TO PUT DEFAULT VERSION OR MAYBE THROW EXCEPTION IF EMPTY>'
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

If you won't check if project has the property (using `hasProperty` method on project instance), `MissingPropertyException` will be thrown.

Comment: I added the script for increasing the buildnumber, can you show me how I could use the generated number in the publishing block?

Comment: @schnawel007, sure. Have a look [here](http://pastebin.com/nGQNPAWf). Please define it as a closure - since gradle has problems with methods - and invoke it as it's shown at the end. Unfortunately I can't check it right now. Passing a `project` instance as an argument might also be not necessary, however please verify the first version at the beginning.

Comment: I have no access to my workstation at the moment. Will have a look at it later on.

Comment: @schnawel007, strange but at my workstation it runs once. Could you provide the whole gradle script?

Comment: @schnawel007, have you solved it finally? Was my answer useful?

Comment: Yes I solved it. It was a task order problem. I reordered  the tasks and now it is working. Who wants to see it, can visit https://github.com/schnawel007/DefaultProject/. You get the bonus, because you tried to help me!

Comment: Great, nice to hear that!